# Passing parameters to ruby methods in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have method inside AplicationController which I want to be reusable from all controllers:

```html
class AplicationController < ActionController::Base
                                                   
protected
                                                   
def set_cartridge_values(cartridge, cartridge_value, param_value)
    @quantity = cartridge.cartridge_value.to_i + param_value.to_i
    cartridge.update(cartridge_value: @quantity)
end
```

I in some controller I want to cal this method like that:

```html
set_cartridge_values(@cartridge, ? ,params[:toner_kg][:weight])
```

In place of  ? mark I dont know how to pass that parameter.

@cartridge - is a varaible defined before

params[:toner_kg][:weight] - is a value

and cartridge_value - is a attribute of a cartridge.

For example I want to pass toner_gr attribute of a cartridge model and update that attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following should work for you:

```
def set_cartridge_values(cartridge, attribute, value)
  @quantity = cartridge.send(cartridge_attribute).to_i + value.to_i
  cartridge.update(cartridge_value => quantity)
end
```

And you call that method like:

```
set_cartridge_values(@cartridge, :toner_gr, params[:toner_kg][:weight])
```

Or you could use [`increment!`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/increment%21) what makes is so short that there is not really a need for an extra method:

```
@cartridge.increment!(:toner_gr, params[:toner_kg][:weight].to_i)
```

Comment: isn't increment deprecated?

Comment: Oh yes, that is the old method on `ActiveRecord::Base` which was removed in Rails 3. Since Rails 3 there is a new method defined on `ActiveRecord::Persistence` (see link in my answer) which does the same.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `send` you could also use

```
def set_cartridge_values(cartridge, cartridge_attribute, value)
  @quantity = cartridge[cartridge_attribute].to_i + value.to_i
  cartridge.update(cartridge_value => quantity)
end
```

Another option is using `read_attribute`

```
@quantity = cartridge.read_attribute(cartridge_attribute).to_i + value.to_i
```

You should use `public_send` if it is should access only public methods of the instance.

```
@quantity = cartridge.public_send(cartridge_attribute).to_i + value.to_i
```

So possible options are,

```
 cartridge[cartridge_attribute]
 cartridge.read_attribute(cartridge_attribute)
 cartridge.public_send(cartridge_attribute)
 cartridge.send(cartridge_attribute)
```